# Exporting a sheet in spreadsheet in csv and pdf

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used the following scripts for exporting two different sheets in a spreadsheet in csv and pdf format.

For `button1` script assigned is `openSidebar` as mentioned below-

```
function openSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("Download");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function createDataUrl(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Names");
  // const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;
  if (type == "csv") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet1.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "pdf") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet1.getSheetId()}`;
  }
  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();
    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet1.getSheetName()}.${type}`,
    };
  }
  return { data: null, filename: null };

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly".
}
```

and for `button2` script assigned is `openSidebarns` as mentioned below-

```
function openSidebarns() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("indexns").setTitle("Download");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function createDataUrl(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Salaries");
  // const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;
  if (type == "csv") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "pdf") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  }
  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();
    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet.getSheetName()}.${type}`,
    };
  }
  return { data: null, filename: null };

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly".
}
```

The problem is that when I click on `button1` I am getting the csv and pdf of `Employees Salaries` instead of `Employee Names`.

`button2` works as expected

The `index.html` and `indexns.html` are both exactly same-

Please advise what have I gone wrong with.

@Tanaike - san

Comment: First, if you are using my sample script, I apologize that my script was not useful for your situation. About your showing script, if you are using your showing script in a single Google Apps Script project, there is the same function name of `createDataUrl`? If my understanding is correct, how about renaming the function names for avoiding the same function name? But, if I misunderstood your current scripts, I apologize. If you cannot understand this, can you provide your current Google Apps Script project?

Comment: Thank you! @Tanaike -san for the response, I tried changing the names of the createDataUrl to ```createDataUrl1```  and ```createDataUrl2``` for the two files respectively and it works now without any problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there are 2 buttons namely `button1` and `button2` which are assigned these two different functions `opensidebar` and ```opensidebarns``.

Note that `createDataUrl` function is the same in both cases which only points to one of the two functions everytime.

To differentiate that, name the `createDataUrl` differently in both cases and the problem will be solved.

`opensidebar`

```
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("Download");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function createDataUrl1(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Names");
  // const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;
  if (type == "csv") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet1.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "pdf") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet1.getSheetId()}`;
  }
  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();
    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet1.getSheetName()}.${type}`,
    };
  }
  return { data: null, filename: null };

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly".
}
```

`index.html` for `opensidebar`

```
<input type="button" value="download as CSV" onclick="download('csv')" />
<input type="button" value="download as PDF" onclick="download('pdf')" />
<script>
  function download(type) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
        if (data && filename) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl1(type);
  }
</script>
```

`opensidebarns`

```
function openSidebarns() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("indexns").setTitle("Download");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function createDataUrl2(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Salaries");
  // const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;
  if (type == "csv") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "pdf") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  }
  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();
    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet.getSheetName()}.${type}`,
    };
  }
  return { data: null, filename: null };

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly".
}
```

`indexns.html` for `opensidebarns`

```
<input type="button" value="download as CSV" onclick="download('csv')" />
<input type="button" value="download as PDF" onclick="download('pdf')" />
<script>
  function download(type) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
        if (data && filename) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl2(type);
  }
</script>
```